# Uncaught TypeError: modal.on(...).trigger is not a function when using Zurb Foundation 5.5.3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation v5.5.3 with a Laravel 5.1 project. I have a modal that was working properly yesterday but has for some reason started throwing an `Uncaught TypeError: modal.on(...).trigger is not a function` error now whenever I click on the button that is supposed to launch the modal.

I researched as much as I could on the issue, but this problem seems to be unique. I had originally tried wiping my `composer.json` file and running `composer install`, then my `node_modules` folder and reinstalled with `sudo npm install`. Eventually I deleted the whole project and pulled the master branch from git. Still no luck.

The oddest part is that my coworkers are using the *exact* same version of Foundation as well as the same Laravel 5.1 project that we're working on and **their modals work just fine**. I don't understand how I can have exactly the same setup and for mine to be the only that doesn't work. All other Foundation-related JS is working normally.

This is what the HTML looks like:

```
<section class="row">
    <article class="small-centered medium-6 column text-center">
        <h2>You haven't uploaded any files yet.</h2>
        <p>
            <a href="https://adder.local/support" target="_support">Follow our guide here</a>.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="button radius small" data-reveal-id="new-upload">New File</a>
    </article>
</section>

<div id="new-upload" class="reveal-modal small" role="dialog" data-reveal>
    <label>Upload Log File</label>
    <input type="file" name="logfile">
</div>
```

Has anyone ever come across this issue? How did you fix it? If not, what steps would recommend (that I haven't tried) to fix this issue and what would be causing this to happen only on *my* machine?

Comment: Is an ad blocker interfering? Just guessing.

Comment: @ClaytonLeis No, I don't have an adblocker installed. The problem is the same on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: This just started happening to me as well. Same project: one computer works completely fine, another computer modals don't work (slightly older MBP, same software version). Currently looking for a resolution...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery recently updated (v2.2) which breaks reveal in Foundation v5.5.3.

**Rolling back to jQuery v2.1.4 resolves the issue.**

```
$ bower install --save jquery#2.1.4
```

Ref: https://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/37579-reveal-stopped-working

Comment: Where to find out which meteor/jquery package version corresponds with the jQuery version used? After updating meteor to v1.3 - and with it jQuery, I guess - my reveal modals broke.